# Get property of DBus interface in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, dbus, networkmanager

I would like to check current network connection is metered or not. In the Bash I can run:

```
qdbus --system org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Metered
```

But I want do it in Python.

I wrote a piece of code that gets the necessary interface:

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
interface = dbus.Interface(
    bus.get_object(
        'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager',
        '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager'
    ),
    dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'
)
```

And I can get any method, such as `GetDevices()`:

```
method = interface.get_dbus_method('GetDevices')
```

And it works (`print(method())`):

```
dbus.Array([dbus.ObjectPath('/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2'), dbus.ObjectPath('/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/14')], signature=dbus.Signature('o'))
```

But how do I get the `Metered` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the more modern D-Bus libraries that are around and try to be more pythonic in how they work. I personally find [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) very easy to get up and running with.

```py
from pydbus import SystemBus

bus = SystemBus()
network_manager = bus.get('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager')
print("Metered is:", network_manager.Metered)
```

If you want to do it with the dbus library then it would be like this:

```py
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()

network_manager_props = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(
    'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager',
    '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager'),
    dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)

metered = network_manager_props.Get(
            "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager", 'Metered')
print("Metered is:", metered)
```